# SAS find in order variables

Tags: sas

I need to find who has in order A-B-C. Please check the table for example;

```
 id          term        grade      subj      num
 10         2002        D            332        1 
 10         2002        A             333      2
 11         2005        C             232       1 
 11         2005        A             232       2
 11         2005        B             232       3
 11         2005        C             232       4
 15         2010       A              130       1
 15         2010       B               130      2
 15         2010       C              130       3 
 20         2000       B             500        1
 20         2000       A             500        2
 20         2000       C             500        3
```

What i need fromthis table is  id : 11 AND 15

The output should be like

```
   id   term   subj
   11   2005   232
   15  2010    130
```

So i need list the id's that had Grade of 'A' in it then was changed to 'B' then it was changed to 'C' .
Num could be in order. It dosen't have to start from 1, it could be 1 or 2 or 3, etc. But it  should be in order A then B then C
I dont need to see the ID=20 bec for the num order grades' are not in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are looking for is a simple 'A'-'B'-'C' sequence, then the `LAG()` function is sufficient. That is what I show in the example below. If you are looking for more sequences (e.g. 'A'-'B', 'B'-'C', 'A'-'B'-'C'-'D'), a slightly more complex solution is needed.  If so, I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Below is a test program showing the implementation:

```
DATA d1;
    INPUT
        id  :8.
        term    :8.
        grade   :$2.
        subj    :8.
        num     :8.
    ;

    DATALINES;
         10         2002        D            332        1 
         10         2002        A             333      2
         11         2005        C             232       1 
         11         2005        A             232       2
         11         2005        B             232       3
         11         2005        C             232       4
         15         2010       A              130       1
         15         2010       B               130      2
         15         2010       C              130       3 
    ;
RUN;



DATA d2 (
    KEEP = id term subj
);
    SET d1;

    grade_previous_1 = LAG1(grade);
    grade_previous_2 = LAG2(grade);

    IF (grade = 'C' AND grade_previous_1 = 'B' AND grade_previous_2 = 'A');
RUN;
```

Note that the `LAG` functions must be evaluated on their own lines and stored in variables, as shown above - don't fold them into the `IF` conditions or they won't always get executed.  That is, don't say:

```
IF (grade = 'C' AND LAG1(grade) = 'B' AND LAG2(grade) = 'A');
```

That actually works in this example but in general it's better to get into the habit of calling `LAG()` outside of `IF` conditions and storing results in temporary variables.

Comment: Your sample output does not show grades. It seemed to me you only wanted the `id`, `term`, and `subj` of record sets containing an 'A'-'B'-'C' sequence, no?  Also, I shortened the code.

Comment: Yes as you mentioned it is not in order. i need that in order 'num'. if i remove 'if ( grade ' part, what i need to add?

Comment: Don;t worry for the first comment, i deleted. i made mistake. But i need output in order A then B then C

Comment: OK, that is different from the current sample output.  Are you saying that you want all the records from each 'A'-'B'-'C' sequence?  If so, please change the sample output just so I'm sure what you mean and then I'll go ahead and change the answer.

Comment: I changed. I added one more id=20 and i don;t need to see that. Because it is not in order. Is that clear?

Comment: Under the phrase "The output should be like", you show some output:  two rows, with fields `id`, `term`, and `subj`.  That is the output my code - the contents of `d2`.  I am not sure what else to tell you.